# Is there any way to delete subscriber on the basis of certain criteria in Marketing cloud.

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, ssjs

Subscribers can be deleted from the lists but what we want to do is to delete the subscriber who has not responded in last 12 months. We have looked into the marketing cloud but couldn't find a way to do this. Is this even possible

Comment: What @lukas said, but it’s not really best practice to delete subscribers from the all subscribers table.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend following approach:

1. Create a sendable Data Extension
2. Create a Query Activity in Automation Studio, populating the above Data Extension with Subscribers you wish to delete
3. Create an SSJS activity which iterates through this same Data Extension and calls the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm) for [Contact Deletion Framework](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5)- remember Contact Deletion must be enabled on the account
4. Put both the Query and SSJS activity in an automation, which you can schedule to run e.g.weekly

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a sendable data extension which includes everyone you want to delete (you'll have to populate it using an SQL query through Automation Studio) but then you can use the 'Contact Delete' function in **Contact Builder**.

1. Go to Contact Builder
2. Click 'All Contacts'
3. Click the trash can icon in the top right
4. Choose 'Delete contacts from data extension'
5. You can then indicate the data extension which contains your contacts for deletion.